# Use local variables or access multiple times a struct value ( C++ )

Tags: c++, performance, local-variables

in JS it a good practice to create a variable, for reusing, instead of access the value in a deep object structure:

```
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
  var someValueINeedOftenHere = arr[i].path.to.value;
  // do several things with this var..
}
```

So instead of finding the value in this deep object structure, we store it locally and we can reuse it over and over again. This should be a good practice, not only because it lets you write cleaner code, but also because of performance.

So, when I am writing C++ code, and I've to iterate over a vector, which holds a lot of structs / objects. Is then the same, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I think you will find an answer to your question [in this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133675/c-structs-slower-to-access-than-basic-variables). Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, in C/C++ it doesn't matter. In C and C++, the memory layout of every structure is known at compile-time. When you type `arr[i].path.to.value`, that's going to be essentially the same as `*(&arr[0] + i * (something) + offset_1 + offset_2 + offset_3)`, and all that will get simplified at compile-time to something like `*(&arr[0] + i * (something) + something)`. And those `something`'s will be computed by the compiler and hard-coded into the binary, so effectively looking up `arr[i].path.to` is not faster than `arr[i].path.to.value`.

This is not mandated by the standard or anything as far as I know, but it's how most compilers will actually work.

If you want to be sure in some specific case, you can look at godbolt and see what assembly it cooks up: http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Note that I'm assuming that when you make the local variable, you are taking a reference to the value `arr[i].path.to.value`, which is most similar to what you do in javascript. If you actually copy the value to a new variable then that will create some copying overhead. I don't think that copying it would be advantageous w.r.t. cache misses unless the usage pattern is pretty complicated. Once you access `arr[i].path.to.value` once, all the stuff around it is going to be in the cache, and there's no reason that copying it onto the stack would make anything faster.

Comment: Thx. So, it would just simplify my code, but it wouldn't really affect the performance, right?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if none of `arr`, `arr[i]`, `path`, `to`, `value` are/involve references/pointers, as [pointed out by Chris Beck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417604/3425536).

However, if any of `arr`, `arr[i]`, `path`, `to`, `value` is/involves a reference/pointer then accessing them will possibly be a cache miss. Accessing them many times makes it multiple cache misses (probably).

Storing a reference/pointer directly to `value` might therefore be more efficient than getting multiple cache misses while chasing the pointer(s) to get to `value`. Bear in mind the compiler will probably optimize things like this anyway.

Storing `value` as a copy might be more efficient if it avoids cache misses, and it's relatively light to copy, and you don't need to modify the original value. Again, the compiler will most probably optimize these cases as well if it's clear that doing so will give a performance improvement.

It all depends. *Only optimize if it's been proven to be a problem*.